# Magento Product Page throwing 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, category, database, error

I had set up an eCommerce site using Magento 1.9 which is working fine at local instance. I just moved my local instance to the server, everything goes right, but in product page it is throwing 404 error not found.

Here is the exception showing in `exception.log` file
 please help me to resolve this issue.

Here is my link `http://beta.cstoremaster.com/store-suppies/2-1-4-x-80-thermal-48-ct.html`

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1,
>   query was: `` SELECT `catalog_category_entity`.* FROM
>   `catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)' `` in
>   lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235

```
#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `catalog...', Array)
#5 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(943): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(698): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#8 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category), NULL)
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(142): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_getProductCollection()
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List->_beforeToHtml()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('right', true)
#16 app/design/frontend/default/ma_sagitta/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(55): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('right')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/chroot/home/be...')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(147): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(2041, Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
#25 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#29 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#30 index.php(85): Mage::run('', 'store')
#31 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database and run this SQL query:

INSERT INTO `report_event_types` (`event_type_id`, `event_name`, `customer_login`) VALUES

```
(1, 'catalog_product_view', 1),
(2, 'sendfriend_product', 1),
(3, 'catalog_product_compare_add_product', 1),
(4, 'checkout_cart_add_product', 1),
(5, 'wishlist_add_product', 1),
(6, 'wishlist_share', 1);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Magento StackExchange. Would you mind elaborating on the first part of your answer to explain *why* it might work or *how* it might solve the problem?

Comment: Please check this below solution as well. It might be helpful for you.

Have a look at the Url Rewrtie Section in the admin to see if a rewrite is added for this product is giving you a 404 error.

Comment: i followed your steps & also done this compilation process. System>Tools>Compilation.,it seems works while page loading it shows the product name on title,but it didn't display any content in the page showing blank white page only @Abhinav Singh

Comment: still i'm facing the same error,help me to resolve this issue @AbhinavSingh